# Trying to make a light bulb using HTML & CSS & JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>3 Circle</title>
    <style>
  body {background: black;}
  .container {display: flex;}    


    .circle {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 250px;
      -moz-border-radius: 250px;
      border-radius: 250px;
      background: white;
    }

    .active {
        background: yellow !important;
        color: red;
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>

<section class="container">
    <button class="circle circle1">Circle1</button>
    <button class="circle circle2">Circle2</button>
    <button class="circle circle3">Circle3</button>
</section>

<script>
    let cir1 = document.querySelector('.circle1')
    let cir2 = document.querySelector('.circle2')
    let cir3 = document.querySelector('.circle3')
    let allCircle = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');

    cir1.addEventListener('onClick', onButton1Click);
    cir2.addEventListener('onClick', onButton2Click);
    cir3.addEventListener('onClick', onButton3Click);

    function onButton1Click() {
        if (cir1.classList.contains("active")) {
            allCircle.classList.remove('active');
        } else {
            allCircle.classList.remove('active');
            cir1.classList.add('active');
        }
    }

    function onButton2Click() {
        if (cir2.classList.contains("active")) {
            allCircle.classList.remove('active');
        } else {
            allCircle.classList.remove('active');
            cir2.classList.add('active');
        }
    }

    function onButton3Click() {
        if (cir3.classList.contains("active")) {
            allCircle.classList.remove('active');
        } else {
            allCircle.classList.remove('active');
            cir3.classList.add('active');
        }
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make 3 light bulbs represented by circles using HTML & CSS.
So if I turn one light bulb on using the button, the other ones should turn off using the addeventlistener. I can't find ways to make the light bulb turn yellow. Is there anything I am doing wrong? I looked for typos but I can't find any.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Are there any errors in the console? What have you tried to solve this on your own? And have a look at [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) which explains how the snippet editor works and how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: `"onClick"` isn't part of the standards events, maybe you meant `"click"`, a NodeList (as returned by `document.querySelectorAll()` doens't have a `classList` property, maybe you wanted to loop through all its Nodes instead, and there might be other issues I don't want to spent too much time searching for.

Comment: 213circle.html:82 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'remove' of undefined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onButton3Click (3circle.html:82)                  I keep getting this error whenever I keep clicking on the circle.

Comment: If you get this error then the code in your question is not the actual code.

Answer (score 5):

A few small things need to changed here.

1. The event type to be passed to the addEventListener is 'click' rather than 'onClick'.
2. The variable `allCircle` returns a list of dom nodes and not a single dom node. So it is essentially a []. Hence properties and methods that are available on a dom node are not accessible on the variable. What you can rather do is write a loop to access each element of the array and then modify their classes one by one

Might also suggest you to put `debugger` inside your code to see what is happening line by line. [This article by Google should help you on using the Chrome dev tools.](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/)

This is my first answer on Stack Overflow.

```js
let cir1 = document.querySelector('.circle1')
let cir2 = document.querySelector('.circle2')
let cir3 = document.querySelector('.circle3')

cir1.addEventListener('click', onButton1Click);
cir2.addEventListener('click', onButton2Click);
cir3.addEventListener('click', onButton3Click);


function removeActive() {
  cir1.classList.remove('active');
  cir2.classList.remove('active');
  cir3.classList.remove('active');
}

function onButton1Click() {
  removeActive();
  cir1.classList.add('active');
}

function onButton2Click() {
  removeActive();
  cir2.classList.add('active');
}

function onButton3Click() {
  removeActive();
  cir3.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.circle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 250px;
  -moz-border-radius: 250px;
  border-radius: 250px;
  background: white;
}

.active {
  background: yellow !important;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>3 Circle</title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="container">
    <button class="circle circle1">Circle1</button>
    <button class="circle circle2">Circle2</button>
    <button class="circle circle3">Circle3</button>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be two issues here.

1. When adding an event listener for a click event, it must be called with `click` that is to be passed as the first parameter to the listener, but you've added `onClick`
2. `querySelectorAll` returns a `HTMLCollection`. So `classList` will not be a valid property on it. You might want to loop through the elements from `allCircles` to remove the class.

I've modified the listener and corrected the classist related fix for the first button here https://jsfiddle.net/gr33nw1zard/y7f5wnda/

Answer (score 1):

should be click event, not 'onClick'.
cir1.addEventListener('**click**', onButton1Click);

Answer (score 1):

Created one common function for all 3 buttons. `onClick` event is not available in plain `javascript`, it's the `click` that is the correct keyword here. Also, you have to iterate over `allCircle`'s object or use `getElementsByClass`. This will work for you!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>3 Circle</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background: black;
    }
    
    .container {
      display: flex;
    }
    
    .circle {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 250px;
      -moz-border-radius: 250px;
      border-radius: 250px;
      background: white;
    }
    
    .active {
      background: yellow !important;
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <section class="container">
    <button class="circle circle1">Circle1</button>
    <button class="circle circle2">Circle2</button>
    <button class="circle circle3">Circle3</button>
  </section>

  <script>
    let cir1 = document.querySelector('.circle1')
    let cir2 = document.querySelector('.circle2')
    let cir3 = document.querySelector('.circle3')
    let allCircle = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');

    cir1.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
    cir2.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);
    cir3.addEventListener('click', onButtonClick);

    function onButtonClick(e) {
      const cir = e.toElement;

      if (cir.classList.contains("active")) {
        Object.keys(allCircle).map(circle => allCircle[circle].classList.remove('active'));
      } else {
        Object.keys(allCircle).map(circle => allCircle[circle].classList.remove('active'));
        cir.classList.add('active');
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `onClick` should be edited to `click`